# Saying working sequentially and alternately

Tags: american-english

I have several work experiences as data engineer and data analyst which sums up like this

1. 2010-2011, data engineer at abc.ltd
2. 2011-2012, data analyst at xys.ltd
3. 2012-2013, data engineer at corp.ltd

I'm trying to make a sentence that sums up all that experiences. This sentence is what I have in my mind so far "I worked as data engineer and data analyst with each contract period in different companies sequentially". Does that make sense or is there better sentence?

Comment: No. It means you acted as a data engineer ***and*** a data analyst at each place you worked. And then it goes off the rails and becomes indecipherable.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Start by removing *sequentially* as unneeded.

Comment: You had two periods of employment as a data engineer with two different companies which were separated by a period of employment as a data analyst with a third company. Alternately just list the periods as you have done in the question, it's probably clearer and easier to read.

Comment: "I have worked as a data engineer or data analyst for various companies." It's not really necessary to be more specific, and it just makes it confusing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a request for writing advice—that is, for advice about how to compose a particular sentence fir maximum effectiveness. Such questions are off-topic at this site.